# How to check .Net Core version in launch condition of Visual studio setup project

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-setup-proje, launch-condition

I am trying to make an installer on Visual studio for my C# project that is dependent on .Net Core 2.1. I know I need to look in file directory "C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr" to check if the .NET core is installed or not. but is there a way we can check the specific version?

Answer (score 0):

you can execute `Dotnet --version`, if the command failed, then probably .net core is not installed, if it executes correctly, it will print the version.

Comment: But we cant execute such commands in launch condition. It include file / registry search

Comment: how are you creating the installer?

Comment: Through visual studio 2017 setup project